# Bat file to change IE internet settings

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

We are rolling out a new system at work, and require IE security settings to be set up in a certain way, to be more specific the ActiveX controls need to be set up a certain way.
Now we cant do this via Active Directory as these are in a test environment, so my manager has asked for a bat file which can be double clicked and will make the changes for that computer.
Obviously if there is another option then i am all ears but it must be something simple for someone who is not tech savy to use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IE settings are located in the registry. So if you prepare .reg files for the user, he can import the new settings just by double-clicking on the files.

Here are some articles that can get you started:

[How can I manage Internet Explorer Security Zones via the registry](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/76436/jsi-tip-5130-how-can-i-manage-internet-explorer-security-zones-via-the-registry.html)
[Internet Explorer Restriction](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/442/)
[Internet Explorer security zones registry entries for advanced users](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182569)